# How do I check what versions of cygwin packages are available using apt-cyg and how do I install them?

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, package-management

I recently wanted to upgrade from `perl 5.32` to `perl 5.36` via my cygwin terminal using `apt-cyg` with no success. In particular I tried:

> apt-cyg install perl=5.36.1-1

The error message was:

> Package perl=5.36.1-1 not found or ambiguous name, exiting

I ended up running `setup-x86_64.exe` from Windows explorer in order to install what I wanted.

I am using the version of `apt-cyg` which I got from github using the following command:

> git clone https://github.com/kou1okada/apt-cyg.git